# Can't import .py file, no module named 'filename' error

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm trying to import a .py file into another .py file and I get the error No module named 'filename'

Here's my directory :

```
(local files)/app/__init__.py
(local files)/app/routes.py
(local files)/app/errors.py
(local files)/app/forms.py
(local files)/app/apiDnd.py
```

I'm trying to use apiDnd.py in routes.py

My `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = '../static'
app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes, errors, apiDnd
```

My `routes.py` file :

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify, request, json
from app import app
import apiDnd
```

Everything works fine without the `import apiDnd` line and that's where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `import apiDnd` in `routes.py` with `from . import apiDnd`.